# Sidekiq fake mode run enqueued worker on testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sidekiq

I'm currently facing a problem with testing sidekiq worker with Sidekiq fake mode.

I running the worker as an object, and the worker will create itself, which is the same worker if it meets certain conditions.

The problem is the worker is been pushed into the jobs array, which increase the jobs array size by 1, which is perfect! But it continued and run the worker as well!

```
worker = AvailablePromoJobBulkNotificationWorker.new
it "will create the next worker after the current worker performed." do
    expect { worker.perform(promo.id) }.to change(AvailablePromoJobBulkNotificationWorker.jobs, :size).by(1)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`perform_async` is the method used to create a job.  `perform` will actually run the worker code.

Comment: I understand that `perform` will run the worker, but shouldn't `perform_async` or `perform_in` will just create a job, and not running it?

Comment: Inside the worker, I'm calling `AvailablePromoJobBulkNotificationWorker.perform_in(10.minutes, promo.id)`. it increase the `AvailablePromoJobBulkNotificationWorker.jobs.size` by 1, but It continue to execute it. –

Comment: I'm not aware of that behavior.

Comment: Does it means that I cannot do something like that?  Or it should be working fine with the scenario above, and you haven't faced a problem like that before?